# what is the difference between win32 application, windows form application and console application?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, win32gui

I want to know what is the difference between windows form application, win32application ana console, i know that both the windows form application and win32 application is gui tool, but i want to know when to use one over the other one, and could I convert console application to windows form application ?

Comment: In short: High level (forms), low level (WIN32) and lowest level (console). Also note that you can use forms/WIN32/console functions (even graphical) from all three types.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Windows Form** refers to a .NET application. It's not based directly on the native Windows API, but instead on the .NET infrastructure. Which includes a virtual machine.

**Win32** generally refers to the 32-bit Windows API. However, the `_WIN32` macro is defined for both 32-bit and 64-bit programming. As a Visual Studio project type it includes both GUI and console subsystem API-level programs.

A **Windows subsystem** is a small integer value in the executable's header that tells Windows what kind of services this program needs. This value can be inspected via e.g. Microsoft's `dumpbin` program, e.g. `dumpbin c:\windows\notepad.exe /headers | find "ubs"`. In Windows 9x the `dumpbin` output was available via the file preview functionality, but that feature was discontinued.

Each process in Windows can be associated with one, and at most one, console window.

**GUI subsystem** means that Windows will *NOT* attempt to outfit each instance with an associated console window. The process can however create a console window itself. Usually this subsystem is used for ordinary programs with a graphical user interface (hence, "GUI"), and with most linkers it's specified as "windows".

**Console subsystem** means that Windows will attempt to outfit each instance with an associated console window, creating a new one if necessary.

Note that

- The same source code can be built as console or GUI subsystem. And that's extremely easy to do. Just change the subsystem specification.
- A GUI subsystem executable has standard streams, just as a console subsystem executable has.
- A console subsystem executable can present a graphical user interface, just as a GUI one can.

Also note that

- Microsoft's tools will by default not accept a standard C++ `main` for a GUI subsystem build. However, this non-conforming behavior is easy to fix. Just specify `/entry:mainCRTStartup` in the linker options.

There is no such problem with the GNU tools, that is, g++.

Comment: Just curious. If I compile a piece of code in the GUI sub-system, what's the standard output in this case? For example, if I have a line `printf("hello world\n");` in the code, when is the "hello world" printed to?

Comment: @ZhengLiu: By default the standard streams of a GUI subsystem process are disconnected, null, because by default there is no associated console window. However, you can e.g. redirect the output streams in the command to run the program. Currently, `a >con` does not work, but `a | more` works.

The program can also just create a console window.

To make C or C++ output (as opposed to API level output) work it's then necessary to reopen at least the C level streams.

Answer (score 5):

1. **windows form applications** are applications that use the graphical programming interface frameworks such as .NET, DELPHI, or MFC instead of directly calling the win32 API.
2. On the other hand, **win32 application** usually deals directly with windows api to create applications from bottom up.
3. And **console applications** don't have any graphical interface. Only command line window is used for data input and result output.

Comment: MFC is only available for Win32 apps. I believe the same is true of Delphi. Windows Forms is only available for .Net apps.

Answer (score 5):

A "windows form application" is a GUI .NET app.

A "win32 application" is a native Windows GUI app.

A "console application" is a native app without GUI.

I don't really understand what you exactly mean by "convert" one kind of app to another kind. But. If you are talking about using some IDE and convert a project to another one : YES it is possible. What makes the main difference is the .DLLs you linked your app with. You can configure a project opened as "console" to behave as a "win32" for example. It is not really easy, but it remains possible. Nos if you want to know if a given existing application that you installed can be converted : NO.

Comment: Console apps are normally attached to a console window. However, they have full access to the Win32 API and can create additional GUI windows.